# How does string size impact the run-time in lex and yacc

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

I have a union defined in the yacc file as

```
%union 
{
  char str[MAXSTRLEN];
}

%token <str> IDENTIFIER
```

In the lex file has the following code snippet -

```
<INITIAL>{identifier} {
if(strlen(yytext) > MAXSTRLEN)
  {
    assert(0 && "Error");
  }
  strncpy(yylval.str, yytext, strlen(yytext));
  yylvalStr[strlen(yytext)] = '\0'; 
  return IDENTIFIER;
}
```

I see that as I change the MAXSTRLEN from 10K to 100K the run-time is affected adversely. Could you please indicate what may be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The union describing a `%token` (your monster `%union`) has to be initialized, and can copied around by the parser. It should even show up as part of the parser's stack. Just shuffling around such gigantic strings *each time the parser does something* will shoot performance through the floor.

lex/flex/yacc/byacc/bison/... were designed to handle typical programming languages, where identifiers are a few characters long. If you really need such a limit, it is probably the rare string that gets that big. Use dynamic allocation (`strdup(3)` and friends, make sure to `free(3)` when you are done with the string!) to reduce memory usage.

Comment: Even though, the token is a large array, however when yytext is being copied to yylval.str an strncpy is being used right, so it only uses yytext's size right? What is going on internally? Why should we see such a performance degradation? Also, since this is a char array statically allocated, is freeing memory necessary in this case?

Comment: @mickeyj, I'm talking about shuffling *token* unions of 100K around, not the initial `strcpy(3)`.

Comment: OK, please excuse my ignorance, but one more question, so even though the strcpy happens and only yytext length of characters are used in the union, however the union still has the string which statically allocated 100K characters for a given token of type string. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether all the 100K bits are used or not. Such large string size causes the performance issue? Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @mickeyj, you'd have to check the code generated by `flex` and/or `bison` to make sure (and it could very well depend on your grammar), but I suspect your performance drop is due to copying tokens around.

Comment: But copying of tokens is restricted to the size of the yytext parsed right, so, if yytext parsed is 10 characters, the performance should not drop whether the buffer size is 10k or 100k right or am I missing something fundamentally?

Comment: @mickeyj, when the parser shuffles tokens around, it just copies the *whole structure*, it doesn't know (or care) what it contains, and certainly isn't in a position to decide that only the first 7 bytes are relevant in "foobar"